# Parse Youtube XML

Tags: xml, asp-classic, youtube

I'm using a basic method to parse some Youtube XML data:

This is a sample XML file from Youtube: http://jimpix.co.uk/youtube.xml

I saved it as XML as the XML file is a lot easier to see than the standard Youtube version from Youtube ([see here](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/9TN3VtWwks4))

This is the basic code I'm using to extract the video ID and Title:

```
Dim vurl = "http://jimpix.co.uk/youtube.xml"
Set http = Server.CreateObject("msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")
http.Open "GET", vurl, False
http.Send

Set dom = http.responseXML
Set items = dom.getElementsByTagName("entry")

For Each item In items

Set id = item.getElementsByTagName("name")
If NOT (id IS Nothing) Then 
    var_id = id(0).Text
End If

response.write "<hr>var_id: "&var_id&"</hr>"

Set title = item.getElementsByTagName("title")
If NOT (title IS Nothing) Then 
    var_title = title(0).Text
End If

response.write "<hr>var_title: "&var_title&"</hr>"  
Next
```

I'm stuck trying to get at the video duration, thumbnail and number of plays, as they are not held in simple tags like the ID and title.

For example, ID and title go like this:

```
<entry...>
    <id>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/9TN3VtWwks4</id>
    ...
    <title type="text">
    Sign Language - Multi-Award Winning short film - Director's Cut
    </title>
</entry>
```

But the duration, thumbnail and number of plays are harder to get at:

```
<entry...>
    <media:group>
        <media:thumbnail url="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/9TN3VtWwks4/0.jpg" height="360" width="480" time="00:02:28.500"/>
        <yt:duration seconds="297"/>
        <yt:statistics favoriteCount="0" viewCount="198826"/>
    </media:group>
</entry>
```

I wondered if I could ask for advice please about how to extract these 3 variables from the XML?

Answer (score 0):

you can get the thumbnails like :

```vbs
<%
    set thumbnails = dom.getElementsByTagName("entry/media:group/media:thumbnail")

    if not(thumbnails is Nothing) then
    for each pic in thumbnails
        Response.write "<hr>thumbnail: "&pic.getAttribute("url")&"</hr>"  
    next
    end if
%>
```